# how to one line text format and convert to multi line text?

Tags: perl

I am noob using per so I need some help. For example, I have aminoacids sequance in file. That sequance is in one line. So I need that in one line should be 60 aminoacids. How I could do that using perl?

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific. What are the delimiters of the aminoacids?

Answer (score 1):

```
open my $infile, '<', "/path/to/sequencefile" or die $!;
open my $outfile, '>', "/path/to/newfile" or die $!;

while(my $line = <$infile>) {
    print $outfile join("\n", split(/\s/, $line)) . "\n";
}

close $infile;
close $outfile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small program that sets the width for the result - but it should give you the idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => "fasta_junk.fasta" ,
                           -format => 'fasta');

my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => '>test.dat',
                           -format => 'fasta');

my $lookup = 'GTGCCAGCAGCCGC';
$out->width(20);

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    my $pos = index $seq->seq, $lookup;


    # if $pos != -1, ($lookup not found),
    # or $pos != 0, (found $lookup at first position, thus
    #   no preceding characters).
    if ($pos > 0) {
        my $trunc = $seq->trunc(1,$pos);
        $out->write_seq($trunc);
    }
}
```

It produced this output (with a width of 20),

```
>LM1
AAGTCTGACGGAGCAACGCC
GCGTGTATGAAGAAGGTTTT
CGGATCGTAAAGTACTGTCC
GTTAGAGAAGAACAAGGATA
AGAGTAACTGCTTGTCCCTT
GACGGTATCTAACCAGAAAG
CCACGGCTAACTAC
```

the fasta_junk.fasta file was

```
>LM1
AAGTCTGACGGAGCAACGCCGCGTGTATGAAGAAGGTTTTCGGATCGTAA
AGTACTGTCCGTTAGAGAAGAACAAGGATAAGAGTAACTGCTTGTCCCTT
GACGGTATCTAACCAGAAAGCCACGGCTAACTACGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGG
TAATACGTAGGTGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGATTTATTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGC
GCAGGCGGTCTTTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCCCGGCTTAACCGGGGAG
GGTCATTGGAAACTGGAAGACTGGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAGAGTGGAATTCC
ACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATGTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAG
GCGACTCTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCA
AACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGT
```

You could play for yourself with various widths to see the outcome.